# Pass this.props.params to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and and this is not my own project and I am trying to figure out things.

This is my `index.js` render

```
render() {
    console.log("this.props", this.props.params)
    console.log("slug", this.props.params.brandName)
    var { data, items2 } = this.state 
    let { brandList, brandProducts } = this.props
    var { data } = this.props.brandProducts

    var filterImage = brandList.data.length === 0 ? [] : brandList.data.data.filter((item) => item.slug === this.props.params.brandName)[0].media

    var name = brandList.data.length === 0 ? "" : brandList.data.data.filter((item) => item.slug === this.props.params.brandName)[0].name

    var checkImage = filterImage.length === 0 ? [] : filterImage.filter((item) => item.collection_name === "images")
    var checkBanner = filterImage.length === 0 ? [] : filterImage.filter((item) => item.collection_name === "banner-image")

    return (
        <div>
            {
                this.props.brandList.loading ? <LoadingSection/>
                : <div>
                    <Banner data={checkBanner}/>

                     <div className="row margin-none">
            <div className="col-lg-2" style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
                {
                    _.isEmpty(checkImage)   ? <div className="card shadow rounded mx-auto brand-logo-text card-logo-text"><h2 className="align-middle text-center">{name}</h2></div>
                                            : <img src={checkImage[0].url} className="img-thumbnail shadow mx-auto rounded brand-logo" alt="..."/>

                }
                <AdvancedSearch />

    //some more code here
```

so what I want to happen is, in my `AdvancedSearch.js`, I want to transfer this code.

```
    var filterImage = brandList.data.length === 0 ? [] : brandList.data.data.filter((item) => item.slug === this.props.params.brandName)[0].media

    var name = brandList.data.length === 0 ? "" : brandList.data.data.filter((item) => item.slug === this.props.params.brandName)[0].name

    var checkImage = filterImage.length === 0 ? [] : filterImage.filter((item) => item.collection_name === "images")
```

and this, somewhere in the render in AdvancedSearch

```
{
_.isEmpty(checkImage)   ? <div className="card shadow rounded mx-auto brand-logo-text card-logo-text"><h2 className="align-middle text-center">{name}</h2></div>
: <img src={checkImage[0].url} className="img-thumbnail shadow mx-auto rounded brand-logo" alt="..."/>

}
```

but it says that brandName is undefined.

my route

```
<Route path="/:brand/:brandName" component={Brand} />
```

points to my `index.js`. how can I pass my params from `index.js` to `AdvancedSearch.js` ?

EDIT::

```
console.log("this.props", this.props.params)
```

returns

```
{brand: "seller", brandName: "nestle"}
```

and

```
console.log("slug", this.props.params.brandName)
```

returns

```
nestle
```

Comment: Post your results from `console.log("this.props", this.props.params)
    console.log("slug", this.props.params.brandName)`

Comment: IMO, just pass it via the component: `<AdvancedSearch params={this.props.params} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to send the data from a parent to a child component is through the props.

In your case you could have the following in your index.js file :

```
<AdvancedSearch brandList={this.props.brandList} brandProduct={this.props.brandProducts} params={this.props.params} />
```

In your AdvancedSearch.js do not forget to "catch" those in the variable you are using, meaning to declare again in this file :

```
const { brandList, brandProducts } = this.props
const { data } = this.props.brandProducts
```

also AdvancedSearch has to be a Class component as it refers to "this.props.params", if you make it stateless then refer to props.params and add the props argument in your function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

pass props from parent to child component to access it in child component. suppose you want to access brandName in AdvancedSearch,
you need to add it in parent,then you will be able to access brandName in  child component( AdvancedSearch js file)

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)